# telerik:radgrid how to get all data from backend including pagination

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I am using `telerik:radgrid` and i have an export to excel Button. The Grid has filters and pagination.

The export button generates an excel but only with the data in the page visible and not from the entire radGrid.

Mt Grid PageCount is 6 and I have 15 items with a total of 84... What i need is to retrieve 84 items and not just 15. Thanks

```
 DataTable dtRecords = new DataTable();
            foreach (GridColumn col in ItemsGrid.Columns)
            {
                    DataColumn colString = new DataColumn(uniqueColumnName(col.UniqueName));
                    dtRecords.Columns.Add(colString);
              
            }
            foreach (GridDataItem row in ItemsGrid.Items) // loops through each rows in RadGrid
            {
                DataRow dr = dtRecords.NewRow();
                foreach (GridColumn col in ItemsGrid.Columns) //loops through each column in RadGrid
                {
                        dr[uniqueColumnName(col.UniqueName)] = (row[col.UniqueName].Text);
                    }
               
                dtRecords.Rows.Add(dr);

            }
```

How can i retrieve the data of the entire RadGrid?

Thanks

Comment: Try setting visible to FALSE.  See : https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/exporting/export-formats/xlsx-and-docx-export?force_isolation=true

Comment: HI jdweng, I could not identity witch propery do i set visible to FALSE... I see my PageCount is 6 and I have 15 items with a total of 84... What i need is to retrieve 84 items and not just 15. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here it is explained](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/exporting/export-formats/xlsx-and-docx-export?force_isolation=true)

I have to set AllowPaging in false and Rebind it...

```
 if(ItemsGrid.PageCount >1)
            {
                ItemsGrid.MasterTableView.AllowPaging = false;
                ItemsGrid.MasterTableView.Rebind();
            }
```